# Strange behaviour with Bash, Arrays and empty spaces

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

**Problem:**
Writing a bash script, i'm trying to import a list of products that are inside a csv file into an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
    PRODUCTS=(`csvprintf -f "/home/test/data/input.csv" -x | grep "col2" | sed 's/<col2>//g' | sed 's/<\/col2>//g' | sed -n '1!p' | sed  '$ d' | sed 's/    //g'`)

    echo ${PRODUCTS[@]}
```

In the interactive shell, the result/output looks perfect as following:

```
burger
special fries
juice - 300ml
```

When i use exactly the same commands in bash script, even debugging with `bash -x script.sh`, in the part of `echo ${PRODUCTS[@]}`, the result of array is **all files names located at /home/test/data/** and:

```
burger
special
fries
juice
- 
300ml
```

The array is taking directory list AND messed up newlines. This don't happen in interactive shell (single command line).
Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Since you're not quoting `${PRODUCTS[@]}`, it is subject to word splitting and glob expansion. Not sure what difference `-x` makes, though.

Comment: When you say "interactive shell", is that just the output of the command (`csvprint ... sed ...`)?

Comment: yes, its the output of command when typed in single line at shell. Not in the script file.

Comment: actually i'm trying to use the "bash -x" in the interactive shell just to debug (and try to understand) the script behaviour step by step

Comment: What does the input file look like?

Comment: Welcome ! Not that I know much about csvprintf, but from your command line, it looks like you're transforming your CSV in XML first, then try to get rid of the XML tag. Not sure why. Did you look into using cut instead or is using csvprintf utility mandatory ? And yes, having a look at the input file would be interesting

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) recommends using `mapfile` [instead of word splitting](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207) and to [quote all expansions](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086)

Comment: The input file looks like exactly this:
cod,prod,category,price
1,burger,meals,10.00
2,special fries,meals,6.00
3,juice - 300ml,drinks,3.00

Comment: But the strange is that in the simply command line everything works. The array is populated with the correct data (correct columns, itens, etc) and I can see that doing an "echo ${PRODUCTS[@]}". But when i put the command lines in bash script, the echo seems that the array take some file names inside it, as newlines messed up. 
Everything is already quoted, but i'll take a look at "mapfile" trick.

Comment: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to add the input file? It's very hard to read in comments, and it should be part of the question anyway.

Comment: The only way I can see this working the way you claim it works in your interactive shell is if you set `IFS=` without remembering or telling us.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for [csvprintf](https://github.com/archiecobbs/csvprintf), you're converting the csv into XML and then parsing it with regular expressions. This is generally a very bad idea.

You might want to install [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.1/index.html) then you can do

```
csvcut -c prod input.csv | sed 1d
```

Or you could use a language that comes with a CSV parser module. For example, ruby

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.read("input.csv", :headers=>true).each {|row| puts row["prod"]}'
```

Whichever method you use, read the results into a bash array with this construct

```
mapfile -t products < <(command to extract the product data)
```

Then, to print the array elements:

```
for prod in "${products[@]}"; do echo "$prod"; done
# or
printf "%s\n" "${products[@]}"
```

The quotes around the array expansion are critical. If missing, you'll see one word per line.

---

Tip: don't use ALLCAPS variable names in the shell: leave those for the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then wonder why your script is broken.